# No org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender in 2.1.4

Tags: spring, maven, spring-ws

I have an application using *org.springframework.ws,/em> 2.1.4.RELEASE which is now requires to use SSL.
I was hoping to inject the *org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender* into the *org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate* but that class in not in found.*

I'm using Maven dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Do I have to downgrade to 1.5 if I want to use ? Is there another way using HTTPS with the WebServiceTemplate without downgrading?
TIA

Answer (score 19):

I think, I figured it out - there is a WS support dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-support</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Indeed, the HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender is and has always been in the support jar.

Comment: Don't need to specify  the version of that dependency when adding it to an existing Spring Boot (managed) project.

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpComponentsMessageSender

```
<bean id="messageSender"
    class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="1200000" />
    <property name="readTimeout" value="1200000" />
</bean>
```

you need to have apache htpp components client .jar with the core in classpath.

If you are using Maven jsut add :

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use following maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```